# Can't create folder that will contain the log file

Tags: c++, log4cplus

I using log4cplus. 
I using config file (log4cplus.props) to define the appender.

On the appender i want to create folder (in case its not exist ) that will contain all the log file

```
 log4cplus.appender.MyFileAppender=log4cplus::RollingFileAppender
 log4cplus.appender.MyFileAppender.File=/myLogFolder/logFile.log
 log4cplus.appender.MyFileAppender.MaxFileSize=16MB
 log4cplus.appender.MyFileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=1
 log4cplus.appender.MyFileAppender.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
 log4cplus.appender.MyFileAppender.CreateDirs=true
```

But the folder does not created - and the file does not created also.

How to solve it ?

Comment: Did you check the user privileges?

Comment: @SumitJha yes .. its ok. on  log4net (.net ) its work ok

Comment: `log4cplus.appender.MyFileAppender.CreateDirs=true` ?

Comment: log4cplus.appender.MyFileAppender.CreateDirs is true on my code .. this not solve it

Comment: Is this a Linux or other *NIX platform? Generally, normal users do not have write access into `/` directory thus they cannot create directories.

Comment: this is windows

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at https://log4cplus.sourceforge.io/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1FileAppenderBase.html

There is a property CreateDirs to set.

Comment: this not work - this is MyFileAppender.CreateDirs=true on my code